# How to use screen with PHP shell_exec or exec

Tags: php, shell-exec

How to use a screen command with php shell_exec or exec?
I try to use screen -S screenname and it does not work.. after i run the script i check screen -list and screenname does not exists..
My code: `shell_exec("screen -S screenname", $output);` The `$ouput` is always null.

Comment: `screen` sessions are per user. Is the user that your PHP runs under the same as the user you check with? Also, what kind of output would you expect since you only open a screen session?

Comment: hm, i need to run screen with root user, but i try to use sudo and it not help me..

Comment: running commands with sudo is not the same as being root user

Comment: how i can run screen command as root?

Comment: i try to use su -u root -c "screen -dmS screenname" and it does not work..
sudo -u root screen -dmS screenname also not work..
all this run by nginx, app working with web, another server (in this situation i send request by postman) send GET request to web-server and in PHP file i do this operation

Comment: You could have your webserver running under root user. However I see high security risks here. May I ask what you are trying to achieve by using the screen session, so maybe folks here can suggest different ways of going about this?

Comment: I want to run in screen application (without running into screen application not working after script complete his work), this application written on PHP, that accept request from players (game server on one game), i want to make web interface, that accept request from another server and locate and run game server on my dedicated server.

Comment: This sounds like an odd case for a screen session. I suggest you store your gamedata elsewhere like in a database.

Comment: Database nothing to do with this. I want to locate gameservers on VDS, for communication with VDS i use web interface. Gameserver need to work in container, if it work with no container like screen he appear be offline when i logout in VDS (in this situation when script done his job).

Comment: About gameserver, this is represents a socket PHP application, that run with start.sh script on certain port, and if i run this without container like screen or tmux the server when i disconnect from VDS shutdown.

Comment: What is VDS? I feel like we are missing plenty of background information here why this makes sense - still don't think it does.

Comment: VDS it is dedicated server, virtual dedicated server.

Comment: Don't run your webserver as root. If you use your php code in CLI you can just execute it with your current user. If you want to use it as webservice i recommend you phpseclib: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/2.0/examples.html

Comment: Thank you. You help me and with phpseclib i can connect to SSH, but when i try to connect to screen with screen -x name i got a error `must be connected to the terminal`. Don't you know how to solve this problem?